# Accessing Webmin from Ubuntu Server 12.04LTS

Tags: server, webmin

I have installed webmin 1.630 on my Ubuntu server. It says i have to access `https//ubuntumyname:1000:/` i have lynx web browser intalled so i ran the command

```
lynx https//ubuntumyname:1000:/
```

it responds with unable to locate remote host. I have checked similar problems concerning this issue raised by others but still there is no solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you made a mistake in writing?
Instead of

```
https//ubuntumyname:1000:
```

Try

```
http://ubuntumyname:10000/
```

or

```
http://localhost:10000/
http://127.0.0.1:10000/
```

By default webmin port is 10000, not 1000. Also maybe your computer can not resolve hostname `ubuntumyname`...

Comment: The problem was the port, but now its working fine, appreciated